# How can I override method using C++/CX?

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I am trying to override OnKeyDown method for CommandBar:

```
public ref class myCommandBar: public CommandBar {
protected:
    virtual void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e);
};
```

But I am getting error:

error C3992: 'OnKeyDown': signature of public member contains invalid type 'Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyRoutedEventArgs` is passed by reference, not by value. The signature should be like this:

```cpp
virtual void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs^ e);
```

Comment: Thanks. I also had to mark class as sealed to use in XAML. And I had to add "override" to the method declaration.